# How to remove the tab from the listofalgorithms (ToA)

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, algorithms

How can I remove the tab from the `\listofalgorithms` so that it always starts without indent?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}\listofalgorithms         % print LOA

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Algorithm section}

\begin{algorithm*}[t!]
\caption{Name of Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\item{test}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Provide a working document please

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you can check it out

Comment: If the example would be compilable I would check it out

Comment: @ChristianHupfer now it does compile. Forgot to include a package

Comment: No, it does not compile. `algorithmic` environment seems to be unknown

Comment: Then you are missing a package: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/

Comment: No, I have the full TeXLive 2015 (daily updated) on my computer. It **does** not compile (and `algorithmicx` and `algorithmic` are both on my TeX path) -- Your example is not working

Comment: very strange ..Im using texmaker for compiling on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have the generated the .pdf file of the current code and compiles even without any warnings. Dont understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the way the ToC-entry is set by forcing a `0pt` indent. The default is `1.5em`, which is set as part of the macro `\listofalgorithms` (since [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) uses the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\old@dottedtocline\@dottedtocline
\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}[5]{\old@dottedtocline{#1}{0pt}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Algorithm section}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{Name of Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE test
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

In principle, each `algorithm` entry is set in the ToC using `\l@algorithm` which, based on `float.sty`, is defined as

```
\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}
```

While `\@dottedtocline` actually takes 5 arguments, the first three are set by default to the above choices. The second argument - `1.5em` sets the indentation of each entry, which I've forced to be `0pt` within a group in the above code.

Comment: But this creates a bigger indentation between the numbering and the text compare to the list of figures or tables. How to make it the same? and also increase the number of dots?

Comment: @Kostas: I get exactly the same space for all three (see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Km5ue.png)). If you're not getting this, then you must be doing something different I don't know about. I am able to adjust all the dots using a single command: `\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1} \makeatother` (where you can change the value of `1` to suit your needs.